# very basic java exception handling

Tags: exception

Is there any point in including the "throws ArithmeticException" declaration in the divide method?

```
    try
    {
        divide(10,0);
    }

    catch(ArithmeticException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception caught.");
    }

}

public static void divide(int x, int y) throws ArithmeticException
{
    int result = 0;

    result = x / y;
    System.out.println("Quotient is " + result);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Really depends upon where you want to handle the exception. If you're new to exception handling, this is worth looking at, and somewhat entertaining. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJeLW7kWHtQ

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for it is to catch whether your division is done with the denominator as '0'. Anything that is divided by 0 is infinity. Your program won't be able to interpret the result and therefore an exception error will be thrown for the divide method.

Answer (score 0):

ArithmeticException is only thrown when dividing by zero or when working with BigDecimal and not rounding.  Since your divide method is working with the "int" data type I would just use an if statement that only allows you to do the division of y does not equal zero.

I noticed this is a void method and you are not doing anything other than printing the result. I am not sure if that is your intention but if you need the value you should consider rewriting this to fit your needs.